# Problem installing latex-beamer ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, latex

I tried to install the beamer package using:

```
   apt-get install latex-beamer
```

but I get the answer *Package 'latex-beamer' has no installation candidate*. Then I followed a hint I found:

```
    add-apt-repository ppa:texlive-backports/ppa
```

and got: 
*The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.*

Any hints how to solve my problem?

Comment: Ended up downloading directly from http://sourceforge.net/projects/latex-beamer!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: you should up-vote if it helped you

Answer (score 6):

The way you have chosen is Windows-like.

Debian (thus and Ubuntu) ships TeXLive distribution in deb-packages via APT.

For Beamer you need `beamer.cls` file and other `beamer*.sty` files.

The `beamer.cls` file is located in `texlive-latex-recommended` package (see [search results on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=beamer.cls).

All you need is to install this package

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended
```

As the result you will have all needed Beamer stuff and then include this LaTeX package to your document.

The examples are located in `texlive-latex-recommended-doc` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=beamer+example+tex&searchon=contents).

Comment: I'd like to call out that the first command OP tried matches the beamer documentation as linked by https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Presentations I found this question after doing the exact same thing